# excel VBA how to make the code run automaticly when the user open the file

Tags: vba, excel

i have this code  that check for date and fill the cells in colors based on the date.

what i need is that when the user open the file and write the date the system will check directly the date and fill in the right color.

what happen is that after the user write the date he needs to click on macro icon in order to the code take action.

## code:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim OfficerList(4) As String


For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'

    Select Case VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3))

    Case Is < VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

    Case Is = VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    Case Is > VBA.Date()
        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

   End Select
Next
End Sub
```

can anyone help me ?
or is there any better idea?

Comment: Is the intention that the colour is set once when the value is first entered, and then never changed again (e.g. if they entered 1 November 2017 today, do you want it to permanently stay red)?  Or do you want the cell to change to green once we reach the date at some time in the future?  If you want it to change, you would be better off using conditional formatting.

Comment: i want to change the color and i want to do this task automatically.

Comment: Use this to run macro on workbook open:

    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    ENTER MACRO HERE
    
    End Sub

Comment: But do you want the colour to change again automatically once the date previously entered becomes a past date?  E.g. If they enter 1 November 2017 today (on 6 October 2017) the colour will be set to red - but do you want that date to become green on 2 November 2017 or do you want it to stay red?

Comment: And please clarify whether you want the macro to run "when the user open the file", or whether you want the macro to run "after the user write the date".

Comment: i want the color to change once you reach the date or you passed by.
yes i want to run the macro on opening the file and if its possible when teh user write the date .

Comment: If you want the colours to be updated when the user enters the date, and every colour potentially changed whenever the workbook is subsequently opened, you should use conditional formatting rather than a macro.

Answer (score 0):

This code should get the job done.

```
'This function is called everytime a cell is edited in the worksheet
'NOTE: This macro should be placed in the same worksheet object of your VBA Project
'that has the same worksheet name as the worksheet with all the dates
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim DateCells As Range
    Set DateCells = Range("C2:C5000")

    'If the user changed one of the date cell run the macro, else do nothing
     If (Not Application.Intersect(DateCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing) Then
        test   'Call your macro here
    End If

End Sub

'This function is called everytime the workbook is opened
'NOTE: This macro should be placed in the 'ThisWorkbook' object of your VBA 
Project
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    test    'Call your macro here
End Sub
```